# Mesh is not becoming smooth after rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, modifiers

i bought a model from turbosquid which was created in maya with the hypersmooth modifier. In Blender it has very hard edges. So i used a subsurface modifier and a smooth modifier to make it soft again. In the preview render view in blender it looks perfektly smooth but when i render it out it is still edgy. I now increased the iterations of the smooth modifier, it´s getting better but there are still hard edges. Also the Preview Render looks way more realistic in my opinion than the final render.
Use modifer in render is tunred on of course.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kc269zv8uptjijz/AACsoeVHyZJjrAptTd1f8Uwxa?dl=0

Comment: Use subsurf and shade smooth. Please add images showing the issue.

Comment: I already do, but that don't seems to be enough. I render out some samples later.

Answer (score 0):

So i tried some things but now it´s behaving even more strange. Nothing does what it should do...

Here are some Rendereded Images.
[image: First Render without anything]

Then some Renders with Subsurface and Smooth Modifier. Render Subsurface was on 3 an Smoothing on 2.2 and 3 or 4 Iterations
[image: Subsurface 3 and Smooth 2.2 and 3 Iteraions]
Then i removed all Modifiers but the result was exactly the same so i deleted them. After that everything was perfect smooth, but now there are some strange Artifacts over the lenes.
[image]
After that i tried only Subsurface with render 4
[image]
And Only Smooth with again 2.2 and 3 Iterations but that also does nothing now.
Im totaly confused now... nothing works like it used to be.